# How is $\mathbb{N}$ with only projections $n\to 1$ equivalent to $\text{FinSet}^{op}$

Tags: category-theory

In the nLab article on [Lawvere theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory), it states that the category with objects $\mathbb{N}$ and morphisms generated by $\pi_i\colon n\to 1$ is equivalent to $\text{FinSet}^{op}$.

How can this be? For example, in the former category, it seems all morphisms have codomain 1. While in $\text{FinSet}$, there are many morphisms $m\to n$ for $m\neq 1$, and hence many morphisms whose codomain is *not* 1 in $\text{FinSet}^{op}$.

Comment: $\pi_n: n \to 1?$

Comment: @AlfredYerger: I guess there are $n$ different projection morphisms $n=1\times1\times\dotsb\times1 \to 1$

Comment: @AlfredYerger: I guess it's clear now. If there is a projection morphism $\pi_1\colon 1\times1\to 1$, then there is also a morphism $\pi_1\times 1\colon 1\times1\times1\to 1\times 1$, i.e. an arrow $3\to 2$. So it's _not_ the case that all morphisms have codomain 1...

Comment: Well, probably what you meant is all morphisms are either an identity or have codomain 1.  Still, there's also the fact that there are endomorphisms $n \to n$ which are not isomorphisms.

Comment: But wouldn't you then need it to be something like "the category with finite products" with that presentation, not just the general category with that presentation?

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Right, although they don't say it in the section I excerpted, I guess it's meant to be clear from the context of the article on Lawvere theories that they must mean $\mathbb{N}$ as a category with finite products. "Include these morphisms and also any products of these morphisms".

Comment: Yes, "generated" has to be understood to mean "generated as a Lawvere theory,"

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Right on. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have resolved this issue, but for future visitors:

The first thing to note is while $1$ is often used to indicate the terminal object of a category, in the context of Lawvere theories it is instead meant to represent the 1-fold product of some "dummy" object. So $\pi_i : n \to 1$ means a projection from the $n$-fold product to the $1$-fold product. To minimize this sort of confusion, I usually put the numerals in square brackets, e.g. $\pi_i : [n]\to[1]$. With this notation, the terminal object is actually $[0]$.

The statement on the nLab page is that the Lawvere theory generated from no operations and no equations is equivalent to $\mathbf{FinSet}^{op}$. That is, the category with finite-products freely generated from a single object, $X$, with no additional arrows or equations is equivalent to $\mathbf{FinSet}^{op}$.  The objects of this category up to canonical isomorphism will be finite products of the single object, $X^n$, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The arrows are composites of the projections, $\pi_i:[n]\to[1]$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and the $n$-fold tupling of any $n$ arrows with a common domain, i.e. $\langle f_1,\dots,f_n \rangle : X^m\to\prod_{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}}X^{n_i}\cong X^{\sum_{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}}n_i}$ where $f_i : X^m \to X^{n_i}$. This includes the $0$-fold case, $\langle\rangle: X^m\to X^0$. These arrows satisfy the usual laws for categorical products.

To make the connection to $\mathbf{FinSet}^{op}$, we note that the universal property of products means that every arrow $X^m\to X^n$ is a tupling of arrows $\langle f_1,\dots,f_n \rangle$ for $f_i : X^m\to X^1$. By induction on the length of a composition, we can show any arrow $X^m\to X^1$ is equal to one of the projections $\pi_i$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$. That is, every arrow $X^m\to X^n$ looks like $\langle \pi_{\varphi(1)},\dots,\pi_{\varphi(n)}\rangle$ for some function $\varphi: \{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,m\}$, i.e. $X^{\varphi}$. Thus, every arrow gives rise to a finite set function, and clearly each finite set function produces an arrow. It's easy to check functoriality using the universal property of products. Explicitly constructing the equivalence (i.e. the pair of natural isomorphisms) rather than relying on full, faithful, and essentially surjective implies equivalence is straightforward.